# 2 Storyboards and 1 PickerView

Tags: storyboard, ios6, uipickerview, iphone-5

I have 2 storyboards one is for an iPhone 5 and the other for the 4s/4/3. I made my picker programmitcally and I positioned it accordingly so it fits on the iphone 5 with this code

```
 picker1 = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 272.5, 294, 219
                                                        )];
```

etc.

But when I run it on my iPhone 4 it is too low and I dont want to ruin my iphone 5 since Ive spent the last two days perfect everything on it. Is there a way to have the iphone load the same picker but at different sizes and coordinates based on the screen size for instance if screen == 568 ..... else ....

??
This is the last step in my app. Any clue how to complete this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should provide what you're after:

```
CGRect iphone5frame = CGRectMake(13, 272.5, 294, 219);
CGRect iphone4frame = CGRectMake(13, 272.5, 294, 219); // Edit these values for the iPhone 4
picker1 = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height <= 480.0 ? iphone4frame : iphone5frame)];
```

**EDIT:** Updated code for more customization

Comment: so i would basically just copy my picker1 = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 272.5, 294, 219
                                                        )]; where you put the ( ) and make it fit the iphone 4?

Comment: You would replace the line you posted with the lines I provided and replace the `(whatever you want on the non-iPhone 5 display)` with a proper number suited for an iPhone 4S/4/3/etc display.  If this works for you please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: to be honest i'm a bit lost on what goes after the int retina35= ? so for example i'd put int retina35 = (13,272.5,294,219); that would be the size and position of the picker on the iPhone4?

Comment: The variable `retina40` contains the `y` location you would like your UIPickerView to be at on the iPhone 5.  The variable `retina35` should contain the same value except targeted for the iPhone 4S/4/3/etc.

Comment: it works. I just had one question more. Can i change the size of the picker on the iphone 4 and keep the size on the iphone 5 the same as it was. It is too big on the 4 and perfect on the 5

Comment: would it just be adding more variables in the 'retina35'

Comment: I updated my answer to allow full customization of both frames.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH YOU ARE A LIFE SAVER! Everything works. You sir just helped me complete my first app. thanks